# Erro ao usar $_SESSION[] com unserialize: "expects parameter 1 to be string"

Tags: php, session

preciso de ajuda para encontrar um erro.

Pelo que parece é um assinatura BOM quem esta aparecendo antes do `session_start()`.
Já procurei em todos arquivos (pelo `Notepad++`) e todos estão `utf-8 sem BOM`.

A estrutura das minha páginas são dessa forma:

```
<?php
  require_once("testaAdmin.php");
  require_once("../_global/_erros/erros.ini");
  require_once("../_controlls/_util/Constantes.php");
  $constantes = new Constantes();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title><?php echo $constantes->getTituloSiteAdmin(); ?></title>
 <?php  require_once("../_global/_meta/meta.ini"); ?>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../_img/favicon.ico" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_global/_css/admin.css" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_global/_css/menu.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="topo"><h1><?php echo $constantes->getCabecalhoAdmin(); ?></h1></div>
   <div id="menu">
      <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once($menu.".php"); ?></div>
   </div>
   <div id="cont">
     <?php   
        if($adminLogado->getTipo() != "s" && $_GET["admin"] != $adminLogado->getIdAdmins())       {
            echo "<h1 class='h1CentralizadoAvisos'>Você não tem autorização para alterar este Administrador</h1>";
        }
        else  {
        ?>
            <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once("administradoresEditarConteudo.php"); ?></div>
        <?php
        }
      ?>
   </div>   
   <div id="base">
      <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once($base.".php"); ?></div>
   </div>
   <div id="final">
      <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once("final.php"); ?></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A página `testaAdmin.php`

```
<?php  
  session_start();

  header  ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

  require_once("../_controlls/_models/Admins.php");
  require_once("../_controlls/_util/TestaAdmin.php");

  $testaAdmin = new TestaAdmin();
  $testaAdmin->validaAdmin($_SESSION["admin"]);

  if(!$testaAdmin->getAdminValido())  {

      echo "<script>location.href='index.php?erroadmin=".urlencode('Voc&ecirc; n&atilde;o esta logado. Por favor faça Login')."'</script>";


  } else {

      $adminLogado = unserialize($_SESSION["admin"]);

      if ($adminLogado->getBloqueado() == "s") {

          session_destroy();
          echo "<script>location.href='index.php?erroadmin=".urlencode('Administrador Bloqueado. Por favor faça contato com o gerente Administrador!')."'</script>";


      }
      $testaAdmin->setTextoCabecalho($adminLogado);
      $testaAdmin->setMenu($adminLogado);
      $testaAdmin->setBase($adminLogado);

      $menu = $testaAdmin->getMenu();
      $base = $testaAdmin->getBase();

      echo $testaAdmin->getTextoCabecalho();
  }
?>
```

Todas as minhas páginas seguem este esquema e se diferem apenas nas páginas de conteúdo.

Apenas uma página esta esse erro

```
Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/dimoveis/public_html/novo/admin/testaAdmin.php on line 19

Fatal error: Call to a member function getBloqueado() on a non-object in /home/dimoveis/public_html/novo/admin/testaAdmin.php on line 21
```

Segue a Classe `TestaAdmin`

```
<?php
  class TestaAdmin {    

     private $adminValido;
     private $textoCabecalho;
     private $menu;
     private $base;

     public function __construct () {
     }

     public function validaAdmin ($sessao) {

        $this->adminValido = isset($sessao)  ? true : false;

     }

     public function setTextoCabecalho ($admin) {

        $this->textoCabecalho = "<h6 style='text-align:center; width:1000px;'>Seja bem vindo Administrador ". $admin->getNome()." => <a href='logout.php' style='color:#000'>Sair</a></h6><br /><br />";

     }

     public function setMenu ($admin) {

        $this->menu = ($admin->getTipo() == "s") ? "menu" : "menu2";

     }

     public function setBase ($admin) {

        $this->base = ($admin->getTipo() == "c") ? "base2" : "base";
     }

     public function getAdminValido() {
         return $this->adminValido;
     }

     public function getTextoCabecalho() {
         return $this->textoCabecalho;
     }

      public function getMenu () {
          return $this->menu;
      }

      public function getBase () {
          return $this->base;
      }


  }
?>
```

Onde estará esse erro?

Classe `Admins`

```
<?php 

 class Admins {

     private $idAdmins;
     private $tipo;
     private $nome;
     private $login;
     private $senha;
     private $bloqueado;

     public function __construct ($_tipo, $_nome, $_login, $_senha, $_bloqueado) {       
         $this->tipo = $_tipo;
         $this->nome = $_nome;
         $this->login = $_login;
         $this->senha = $_senha;
         $this->bloqueado = $_bloqueado;
     }

     public function setIdAdmins ($_idAdmins) {
         $this->idAdmins = $_idAdmins;
     }

     public function getIdAdmins () {
         return $this->idAdmins;
     }

     public function getTipo () {
         return $this->tipo;
     }

     public function getNome () {
         return $this->nome;
     }

     public function getLogin () {
         return $this->login;
     }

     public function getSenha () {
         return $this->senha;
     }

     public function getBloqueado () {
         return $this->bloqueado;
     }

 }
?>
```

logon.php

```
<?php
require_once "../_controlls/_conexao/Conexao.php";
require_once "../_controlls/_models/Admins.php";
require_once "../_controlls/_daos/AdminsDao.php";


$connection = new Conexao();
$conexao = $connection->abreConexao();
$AdminsDao = new AdminsDao($conexao);

if (!isset($_GET["acao"])) {
    $erroadmin = (isset($_GET["erroadmin"])) ? $_GET["erroadmin"] : "";
?>
  <h1>Logar no Sistema</h1><br />
  <h3 class="avisos"><?php echo $erroadmin; ?></h3>

  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="logar" /> <br />
    <label class="labelPequeno">Login</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="<?php echo $constantes->getLenLogin(); ?>" name="login" required />  <br /> <br />
    <label class="labelPequeno">Senha</label><input type="password" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="<?php echo $constantes->getLenSenha(); ?>" name="senha" required /> <br /> <br />
    </label><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br /> <br />
  </form>

<?php   
}

if (isset($_POST["acao"]) && $_POST["acao"] == "logar") {

      $login = $_POST["login"];
      $senha = $_POST["senha"];

    if( $login == "" || $senha == "" ) {

        echo "<label class='avisos'>erro: Algum campo esta vazio. Verifique</label>";

    } else {

        if ( strlen($login) > $constantes->getLenLogin() || strlen($senha) > $constantes->getLenSenha() ) {

            echo "<label class='avisos'>Login ou Senha com quantidade de caracters errado!</label>";
        } else {

            $admin = $AdminsDao->pesquisaAdmin($login, $senha);

            if($admin == null)  {

                echo "<label class='avisos'>Usuário ou senha inválidos</label>";

            } else {    

                if($admin->getBloqueado() == "s"){

                    echo "<label class='avisos'>".$admin->getNome().": O Administrador geral bloqueou você!</label>";
                } else {                        

                        $_SESSION["admin"] = serialize($admin);

                        echo "<script>location.href='principal.php'</script>";

                }
            }

            $connection->fechaConexao();

        }
    }   

}
?>
```

Comment: O problema não é bem com `session_start`, recomendo que faça titulos mais intuitivos ao problema =) - entenda como uma critica construtiva

Comment: Oh Guilherme, obrigado pelo alô. Vou ficar mais atento. Mas é que na hora, foi esse titulo que me veio à mente que se relacionava mais ao problema que eu entendi estar passando

Comment: Uma duvida Carlos, porque está tentando usar `unserialize` com uma variável de sessão? Não seria melhor manter como variavel e arrays mesmo?

Comment: Na verdade foi a única forma que encontrei de levar a sessão para dentro de um método de um classe para saber se a sessão existe.

Comment: A entendi, você esta enviando os dados da classe, acho que tem maneira mais pratica.

Comment: Queria guardar na sessão o objeto de classe que guarda o administrador logado

Comment: Cara em logon.php na parte onde verifica que está bloqueado vc está chamando um parâmetro get, acredito que queria chamar o método getName. Outra coisa, por acaso o register_globals está ativado?

Comment: é getNome() mesmo. Aqui no meu esta correto. register_globals = on A sessão funciona sim. Já respondi a essa pergunta, confere lá embaixo.

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro é bem clara. Na linha 19 de testaAdmin.php:

```
$adminLogado = unserialize($_SESSION["admin"]);
```

É esperado que o parâmetro de `unserialize()` seja `string`, mas está entrando um `object`. Ou seja, `$_SESSION["admin"]` é um objeto já pronto, não precisa ou não pode ser desserializado.

Fora isso, retire os `?>` dos seus arquivos, quando eles estiverem no final. Evita problema de espaços após o fim do arquivo, que podem ser tão chatos de corrigir quando os espaços invisíveis antes de `<?php`.

Comment: Ok. Mas não dá para entender, e te peço ajuda para isso, porque se todas as páginas funciona, porque será que só nessa esta chegando o objeto? Nem dá para saber como corrigir senão pode influenciar nas demais páginas. Não?

Comment: Se as outras classes funcionam e essa não, provavelmente o que as outras fazem é algo como `$_SESSION["admin"] = serialize($var);`, enquanto que nesse caso está fazendo algo como `$_SESSION["admin"] = $var;`, ou seja, sem o `serialize()`. Procure todos os pontos que tem $_SESSION no seu código até encontrar a linha diferente.

Comment: Aproveitei e lancei no fim da pergunta o logon.php que é onde o objeto é serializado

Comment: o arquivo é o mesmo para todas as classes

Comment: Não importa que o arquivo seja o mesmo. Você só mostrou onde `$_SESSION["admin"]` é **usado**, não onde ele é **preenchido**. Seu código está preenchendo essa variável de maneiras diferentes. É isso que você tem de procurar.

Comment: Aproveitei e lancei no fim da pergunta o logon.php que é onde o objeto é serializado e onde ele é preenchido. Não são outras classes e sim esta página dá erro,

Comment: Procurei no logon.php e não vi nenhum comando `serialize()` e menos ainda um acesso tipo `$_SESSION["admin"]`. Você tem de procurar **TODAS** as linhas do sistema que mexem com `$_SESSION["admin"]` ou `$_SESSION['admin']`. E fazer algo do tipo: `if ( is_object($_SESSION["admin"]) ) throw new \Exception();`

Comment: me perdoe, coloquei o arquivo errado, já acertei o logo correto lá

Comment: Então cara, você tem de procurar em todos os arquivos. Postar os arquivos que dão certo não ajudam a resolver o problema. O erro diz que tem algum lugar que faz `$_SESSION['admin'] = $obj`, e é essa linha que você tem de procurar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38161/discussion-between-andre-lfs-bacci-and-carlos-rocha).

Comment: Não encontro o erro. Aparece isso aqui. Catchable fatal error:  Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string in /home/dimoveis/public_html/novo/admin/testaAdmin.php on line 19. Mas o arquivo desse erro esta sendo usado via require_once em todos os arquivos

Answer (score 0):

Presumo que para resolver bastaria  retirar a função `unserialize()`:

```
$adminLogado = $_SESSION["admin"];
```

Mas enfim, não sei o que contém dentro de `$_SESSION["admin"]`. Por isso, é inviável apontar uma solução com as informações que colocou na pergunta.

A função [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize) espera uma string como parâmetro.

Para lhe indicar uma solução para o seu caso precisamos entender o motivo de querer usar `$adminLogado = unserialize($_SESSION["admin"]);`.

Pressuponho que $_SESSION["admin"] já deveria estar serializado com a função [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize). Mas devido a mensagem de erro, não é o que realmente está acontecendo.

A pergunta é, em que momento `$_SESSION["admin"]` é serializado?
Não li o código inteiro que postou. Se puder mostrar onde isso ocorre, pode facilitar a encontrar o problema.

Para entender melhor o problema, faça um teste para ver qual o tipo da variável:

```
var_dump($_SESSION["admin"]); exit;
$adminLogado = unserialize($_SESSION["admin"]);
```

Informe na sua pergunta o resultado desse teste.

Provavelmente é um array ou um object/stdclass.

Comment: Oi, obrigado pelo retorno. Deixa eu ser mais específico. Trata-se de um ambiente administrativo de um site. Tem um tela de login que é onde a serialização acontece que é o ultimo arquivo listado na pergunta. Após a validação de login, senha e condição de bloqueio, é criado um objeto new Admins($tipo, $nome, $login, $senha, $bloqueado);    Daí em diante, a cada página, preciso validar se esse admin esta ou não logado, o que normalmente faço com seção. Mas não tem como colocar um objeto dentro de uma seção sem sereializar e não tem como usar esse objeto sem serializar

Comment: string(222) "O:6:"Admins":6:{s:16:"AdminsidAdmins";s:1:"1";s:12:"Adminstipo";s:1:"s";s:12:"Adminsnome";s:20:"Carlos Alberto Rocha";s:13:"Adminslogin";s:4:"caca";s:13:"Adminssenha";s:4:"aaaa";s:17:"Adminsbloqueado";s:1:"n";}"

Comment: saída : object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (7) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(6) "Admins" ["idAdmins:private"]=> string(1) "3" ["tipo:private"]=> string(1) "c" ["nome:private"]=> string(5) "Teste" ["login:private"]=> string(4) "test" ["senha:private"]=> string(4) "test" ["bloqueado:private"]=> string(1) "n" } 
Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/dimoveis/public_html/novo/admin/testaAdmin.php on line 23

Fatal error: Call to a member function getBloqueado() on a non-object in /home/dimoveis/public_html/novo/admin/testaAdmin.php on line 25

Comment: Outra informação que talvez seja importante é que isso só acontece na hospedagem. Já no localhost o erro não acontece!

Comment: no arquivo logon.php, vc tem isso: `$admin = $AdminsDao->pesquisaAdmin($login, $senha);`. Na linha seguinte, adicione `var_dump($admin); exit;`. Isso é apenas para debugar. Depois vc pode remover. Mas acredito que resultará o mesmo. Pois acredito que o problema está dentro desse método `$AdminsDao->pesquisaAdmin()`. Precisa ver o que é que tem de errado aí dentro.

Comment: Ocorre que o objeto não esta completo. Já dei a resposta com a solução. Obrigado pelo apoio.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui. A solução foi:

No arquivo do form login, que é onde eu crio a sessão.

No arquivo textaAdmin, que é onde eu texto a sessão.

Acontece, que para podermos pegar TODO o objeto sessionado, é preciso que session_start() seja declarada após a require_once da classe do objeto.

Observação: esse erro não ocorre no localhost. Apenas no servidor.

```
<?php  

  header  ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

  require_once("../_controlls/_models/Admins.php");
  require_once("../_controlls/_util/TestaAdmin.php");        

  session_start();

  $testaAdmin = new TestaAdmin();
  $testaAdmin->validaAdmin($_SESSION["admin"]);
  ...
```

Grato a todas opiniões a respeito da dúvida.

Mas se tivesse como usar o padrão singleton para instanciar a classe TestaAdmin uma só vez e ele guardar para cada página uma cópia do objeto para não usar sessão seria melhor. Mas procurei muito na internet e tentei muito também e nada.

Comment: Cara sinceramente isso que está fazendo é um erro grave. Guarde na sessão apenas o ID do registro no banco e quando instanciar o objeto que trata a sessão você busca no banco as informações. Guardar um objeto inteiro em sessão é muito arriscado, pois sessões podem ser manipuladas de várias formas. Guardando um ID e buscando no banco as informações, você restringe o acesso a várias informações importantes para a segurança do sistema. Sem falar que não teria que serializar e desserializar objetos toda hora, que é um processo muito custoso

Comment: Hum. Esta certo. Vou mudar isso.Obrigado.

Está facil de mudar pois é tudo OO.